# Error :app:installDebug FAILED when run android app, how to solve it?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I try run test app from here https://github.com/Singree/react-native-example-app but when I type `react-native run-android` I get error in :app:installDebug, log here https://pastebin.com/063Np2GX android-studio emulator is launched, how to solve it?

Comment: Try this `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` the execute command if still failed you should go for bundle it and sign it then deploy to device

Comment: i close android studio and open the application then make `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`  and `react-native run-android` ty bro it solved

Comment: I use adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 before react-native run-android otherwise I got batchedbridge error , it created apk but does not install on my android5.1 device , I had to do it manually everytime, I see device if I type adb devices but it does not install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` the execute command if still failed you should go for bundle it and sign it then deploy to device